Edit crontab via Bash script
I need to add a crontab entry only if it's absent. But for some reason I simply cannot write simple script for this.
I have tried this code (and many other suggestions), but it always appends to existing crontab. Nothing changes if I try to express everything with 'if else fi' though. What don't I understand in Bash?
#!/bin/bash
set_cron() {
    # get the current crontab entries
    crontab -l > cron
    # set up new crontab entries
    cron_cmd="0 0 5 * * prosodyctl --root cert import /etc/letsencrypt/live/"
    # append new crontab entries if needed
    grep -q "$cron_cmd" cron || echo "$cron_cmd" >> cron && crontab cron && rm cron
}
set_cron


Did you try using grep by hand to see what the output is?

The * in $cron_cmd have special meaning in a regular expression. Use the -F option to search for a fixed string rather than regexp.
if ! grep -F -q "$cron_cmd" cron; then
    echo "$cron_cmd" >> cron && crontab cron && rm cron
fi


Thanks! That's correct! Now everything works fine.
